# Unable to Execute a jar file with Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:/path/firefox.jar");); when jar needs external files

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a project that opens a browser with selenium. The structure looks something like this:

```
myProyect
   src
     com.open
        OpenFirefox.java
   lib
     geckodriver
        geckodriver.exe
```

If I make a jar file of this, I can only execute the jar if the jar in the same place as `lib/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe`. And both `double click` and `java -jar firefox.jar` from the console works.

Now, I need to execute this jar from another program. I have been opening other jars that have no dependencies with `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);` with no problem, but when I try

```
try {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/firefox.jar");                  
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

nothing happens, I dont even get an error.

What is happening?

Comment: are you sure this jar has an entry point configured?

Comment: i´m just doing right click/export/runnable jar file/finish. Do I need to configure somehting else?

Comment: does it have a main method? and, if so, is this configured in the manifest file in the .jar file? if it doesn't, it isn't an executable jar file, but just a library

Comment: I do have a main method and the main class in the manifest file is the one with the main method (I only have one class)

Comment: Are you using any external libraries?

Comment: yes. Do I need to do something to add them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Runtime.exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))

```
Process process = Runtime.exec("java -jar " + filepath);
if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
    System.out.println("process ran without errors");
}
```